# Language configuration (change url and refresh page on DropDown change)

Tags: php

I am setting up a multilanguage website.

I have a dropdown where there is a set of languages that I cover.

I would like script, when dropdown changes, add or replace variable to url and refresh the page.

I do not want to store language in session or cookie.

My goal is that search egnines indexes all my multilanguage pages and to have url rewritting so my URL would look like http://www.index.php/EN/home, which I will cover later.

Currently I have a DropDown which sumbits form on change:

```
echo "<select name='lang'  onchange='this.form.submit()'>";     
$array = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT code, name FROM languages");
oci_execute($array);

while ($row  = oci_fetch_array($array))
{
    if ($lang == $row[0])
    {
        echo "<option value=".$row[0]." selected='selected'>".$row[0]."</option>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<option value='.$row[0].'>'.$row[0].'</option>';
    }
}            
echo '</select>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<select name='lang' id="dropdown">
    <option value="EN">English</option>
    <option value="FR">French</option>
</select>


<script>

$('#dropdown').change(function()
{

    var langValue = $('#dropdown').val(); // i.e. langValue='EN' or langValue='FR'
    if(langValue)
    {
        window.location.href = 'http://www.index.php/' + langValue + '/home';
        return true;
    }
    return false;

});

function addLang(langValue)
{
    var url = window.location.href;
    var urlP = url.split('/');
    if(urlP.length <4)
    {
        url = url + langValue; // adding new lang
    }
    else
    {
        url[3] = langValue; // replace old lang
        url = url.join('/');
    }
    console.log(url);
}

</script>
```

Comment: My knowledge in java script is very poor but if $('#form') collects all forms tag then your code nothing change. The URL remains same.

Comment: #from means a form with id "form" <form id="form"> and it has to be unique

Comment: Add it, but nothing happens.

Comment: Ok - now it gets executed but doesn't change URL. Code goes in IF statement but URL remains same.

Comment: or may be just use redirection.

Comment: I think redirection is not nice solution for SEO.

Comment: Could you please also provide a code which looks for parameter lang in URL. If it finds it then replace it otherwise add it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks that will be fine. Do you have some other solution instead of redirecting. If I understand this code when user change language it goes to server, back to client, change url, again on server and again back to client?

Comment: No there is no other solution you should have to either post or redirect. You can cache the page with some server side scripting.

Comment: I came up with anoher solution. Wth PHP I will create <a> tags and then use java script to make it like drop down. This will be optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#form').submit(function()
         {
          var lang=$("[name='lang']")val();
           window.location.href='http://www.index.php/' + lang+ '/home';
          }

       });
       });
```

Comment: Guess in your code is some kind of error because if I add alert after document ready and if I comment submit function I get alert, otherwise not. Your code also nothing change.

Comment: I working on solution which mr. Waqar Alamgir gave. Thanks anyway.